# Story/novella about a giant hand from another dimension/universe

Tags: story-identification

I read a story in the sixties, perhaps written earlier, about a post medieval but pre-industrial world where a common fellow gains the ability to call forth a giant hand that he manipulate to do his will. The hand, fist as big as a VW bug, manifests from thin air to battle enemies, destroy and build and is a creation of non magical means. Transdimentional, metaphysical, cerebral mutation,... not sure what the explanation was. Think Green Lantern without a ring and only one trick up his sleeve. It didn't hang around, floating along with the main character, it would appear when needed. And I'm not sure if this was a manifestation of his own physical self or an other world entity. Needless to say it can't be kept secret and the events snowball ala Game of Thrones.
Sorry that I can't recall author or title and if I could, why ask this question. Thanks for any help. 
My Cthulu Mythos story search never got an answer, still... hoping.

Comment: this is all i can think of hearing about giant hands http://www.mariowiki.com/Master_Hand

Comment: I personally thought of Bigby, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigby_%28Greyhawk%29

Comment: This does ring a bell, but I can't place it. If the "fist" is described in the story as "big as a VW Bug" that at least places the writing probably somewhere in the early 1960's to late 70's. Yes, I know the Bug was around before and after this date range, but out of that range it's not referred to that often. Today, an object that size would probably be described as "big as a Mini Cooper" or some such.

Comment: I thought of Wall/Floormasters from Legend of Zelda.

Comment: @TrishLing your not the only one lol

Comment: The VW comparison is my own, not from the story. The size was described but I don't recall the detailed comparison.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This reminded me of Baran of the Extra Hand from Zelazny's ["The Changing Land"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Changing_Land). From the wikipedia page:

> Baran of the Extra Hand is a wizard who has taken control of the
>   fortress and is using the demi-god Tualua to keep outsiders at bay
>   until he can figure out a way to control Tualua without using
>   Semirama, the resurrected Elf queen. Baran has control of a magic
>   giant hand that appears from a magical plane to attack his enemies.

As I recall, it was a floating physical hand, not an energy construct. It gets hacked at with swords at one point and seems to wound like an ordinary, if oversized, hand.

Comment: And Roger has always been a favorite author and sorely missed. Thanks so much, Ihor

Comment: Also forgot the magic basis of the story along with the character's personality/motivation. Early 80's came as a surprise, seemed longer ago.